# change value in drop_down element with javascript

Tags: javascript

enter here

https://accounts.google.com/SignUp

I want to change the value in gender drop_down element

```
No Code // I even can`t select this element
```

Comment: You can't change the code of that page. Only Google Employees can. And Google employees won't ask such questions in StackOverflow. So you are not a Google employee! And you can only change for your view using Inspect Element.

Comment: @PraveenKumar , yes I mean how to change it using inspector (in the console tab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here you go!

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd>.
   [image]
2. Right click on the Male and click Inspect Element.
   [image]
3. Add new value:
   [image]
4. See!
   [image]

Comment: nice , give me the javascript code :D , I want to make this programmatically not (manual = with my hand)

Comment: @AhmedMohsen Try this: `document.querySelector("#Gender").querySelector('[id=":e"]').innerHTML = 'Ahmed'`

Comment: if there`s option to change it by the index , it will be nice idea!

Comment: @AhmedMohsen Oh got it now. Your question wasn't clear.

Comment: @AhmedMohsen Use `document.querySelectorAll("#Gender .goog-flat-menu-button-caption")[0].innerHTML = 'Ahmed'`

Comment: Wow , worked , this solution was in my head
but I ignored it , as you might just changed the "displayed text"
but the actual value has not changed/selected